# Dictionary comprehension sometimes does not work

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a function to store analysis results into a file. It takes `states_` as an input, which is a dictionary of a dictionary. The key is instrument, the value is some error distribution. For example,

```
states_
{'NQH8': {'300=20': 0, '373=71': 0, '373=70': 0, '373=73': 0, '373=72': 0, '373=11': 0, '373=10': 0, '380=1': 0, '380=0': 0, '380=3': 0, '380=2': 0, '380=5': 0, '380=4': 0, '380=7': 0, '380=6': 0, '300=99': 0, '300=2': 0, '300=98': 0, '300=1': 0, '300=3': 0, 'Accepted': 40, '300=5': 0, '300=7': 0, '300=6': 0, '300=9': 0, '300=8': 0, '373=7': 0, '373=6': 0, '373=5': 0, '373=4': 0, '373=3': 0, '373=2': 0, '373=1': 0, '373=0': 0, '373=9': 0, '373=8': 0}, 
 'ESM8': {'300=20': 0, '373=71': 0, '373=70': 0, '373=73': 0, '373=72': 0, '373=11': 0, '373=10': 0, '380=1': 0, '380=0': 0, '380=3': 0, '380=2': 1, '380=5': 0, '380=4': 0, '380=7': 0, '380=6': 0, '300=99': 0, '300=2': 0, '300=98': 0, '300=1': 0, '300=3': 0, 'Accepted': 0, '300=5': 0, '300=7': 0, '300=6': 0, '300=9': 0, '300=8': 0, '373=7': 0, '373=6': 0, '373=5': 0, '373=4': 0, '373=3': 0, '373=2': 0, '373=1': 0, '373=0': 0, '373=9': 0, '373=8': 0}}
```

In the code snippet below, I pick a small set in the error distribution dictionary, using dictionary comprehension (i.e. the commented line). It is expected that the commented line behaves the same as the for-loop.

```
for inst in instruments:
   # rejects = {k:states_[inst][k] for k in ErrorMsg[errorType].keys()} 
   for k in ErrorMsg[errorType].keys():
       rejects[k] = states_[inst][k]
```

However, in reality, it complains `global name states_ not defined`.

```
rejects = {k:states_[inst][k] for k in ErrorMsg[errorType].keys()}
*** NameError: global name 'states_' is not defined.
```

As a matter of fact, when I set break points here, it is ok to display values of states_, but it just can't run that line. Hence, I have to replace it with the for-loop, then it works.

Has anyone encounters this before?

My version of Python is 2.7.5.

Comment: Are you sure `states_` is in the same namespace? I.e. defined at module-level earlier? The code which defines `states_` (unmodified) might help to resolve the problem.

Comment: It looks like you simply omit to properly assign your data to **states_**.

Comment: Both your comprehension and explicit loop use the same name `states_`; I don't see how one could produce the given `NameError` but the other not.

Comment: Can you please post some reproducible code? Have a look at *[mcve]*.